# MSMQ receive timeouts from .NET

Tags: .net, msmq, message-queue

I want to be able to read and process messages from MSMQ. The queues are transactional. I'm currently using this code:

```
while (true)
{
    using (var txn = new MessageQueueTransaction())
    {
        txn.Begin();

        try
        {
            var message = queue.Receive(txn);
            Dispatch(message);

            txn.Commit();
        }
        catch (MessageQueueException ex)
        {
            txn.Abort();
        }
    }
}
```

Where `queue` is a `System.Messaging.MessageQueue`.

I'd like to make the loop use `while (!cancelled)`, which would mean calling the `queue.Receive` that overload that accepts a timeout. However, the code throws when the timeout is reached, and throwing so many exceptions can't be a good thing. Is there a `TryRecieve`, similar to `Monitor.TryEnter`? Peek seems to be the closest, but it also throws when the timeout is reached.

If I want high throughput reading from a queue and cancellation support, what's the best way to read from the queue?

Comment: "throwing so many exceptions can't be a good thing."
Why not? You're catching them . It's not as if anything is going to wear out :-)

One advantage of using a timeout is you can't get in an error situation where the receive never completes. With a timeout the receive will regularly complete and be called again.

Comment: Exceptions shouldn't be thrown in non-exceptional circumstances (a queue being empty isn't exceptional) - they are expensive to throw and add extra objects to the GC to collect among other things.

Comment: Fair points. 
The queue being empty, though, isn't the exception  - it's the timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a direct answer, but I would use the net.msmq protocol in WCF to do my messageQ handling. Its a neat simple approach and can cater for all the scenarios you have mentioned here.

Answer (score 3):

Use MessageQueue.BeginPeek() instead.  The event handler you write for the PeekCompleted event will run as soon as a message is available.  You can call Receive() and be sure you'll get a message without a timeout.  There's a good example in the MSDN Library article.